# Boto3: how to create and tag Virtual Private Gateway [create_vpn_gateway()]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm still getting my head around `boto3` and trying to figure out how to properly create and tag a `Virtual Private Gateway` and attach it to the VPC.

```
ec2_inst = boto.Session(profile_name='my_profile').resource('ec2')
vpg = ec2_inst.create_vpn_gateway(Type='ipsec.1', AmazonSideAsn=64512)
```

But I get: `AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_vpn_gateway'` (probably for the obvious reason). If I change the code to use `client('ec2')` instead, then it works:

```
ec2_inst = boto.Session(profile_name='my_profile').client('ec2')
vpg = ec2_inst.create_vpn_gateway(Type='ipsec.1', AmazonSideAsn=64512)
```

I understand that `resources()` is high-level wrapper around the `client()` and doesn't cover all the client() functionalities but is there a way to use `create_vpn_gateway()` using resource() as I'm using it for the Rest of my code?

Also, how do I `Tag` the created gateway and `attach` to a VPC? This doesn't work either:

```
vpg.create_tags(
    Tags = [ { 'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'MY-VPG' }, ]
)
vpg.attach_to_vpc(VpcId=vpc.vpc_id)
```

giving `AttributeError` for 'dict' object neither having 'create_tags nor 'attach_vpn_gateway' attributes. Any idea how do I do it? Best!

Comment: thanks for the correction, @Oluwafemi Sule!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `boto3.resource` for `ec2` operations, you can access the client from `<ServiceResource>.meta.client`.

```
import boto3

TAGS = [{'Key':'label', 'Value': 'test'}]

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

vpc = list(ec2.vpcs.all())[0]  # or make a new vpc & subnet: 
# https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/1.4.8/docs/source/guide/migrationec2.rst#creating-a-vpc-subnet-and-gateway

operation_result = ec2.meta.client.create_vpn_gateway(Type='ipsec.1')
try:
    gateway_id = operation_result['VpnGateway']['VpnGatewayId'] 
    ec2.meta.client.attach_vpn_gateway(VpcId=vpc.id, VpnGatewayId=gateway_id)

    ec2.create_tags(Tags=TAGS, Resources=[gateway_id])
except KeyError:
    print('Failed to create VPN gateway.')
```

Comment: I think you wanted to say: `ec2.create_tags(Tags=TAGS, Resources=[gateway_id])` instead? with `Resources=[gateway_id]` it renaming the VPC tag.

Comment: @MacUsers Yeah, that's correct. I have edited the code sample